# GET http://localhost:8080/index.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack

I'm just dunno when this happens,I've been working with sass(responsive) and then appears that GET http://localhost:8080/index.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found). The most excited part is that pagination script is working but style(that I haven't touched isn't) that being implemented by scipt won't.I also have facebook ad which scipts are conncted at the top

Removed iframe

```
import './sass/style.scss';
import Slider from './js/sliderHero';
import Paginator from './js/pagination';

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  return {
    Slider,
    Paginator
  };
});
```

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, './dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpe?g|gif)$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options: {
            name: '[name].[hash].[ext]',
            outputPath: 'imgs'
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: ['html-loader']
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/index.html'
    }),
    new MiniCssPlugin({
      filename: '[name].css',
      chunkFilename: '[id].css'
    }),
    new CleanWebpackPlugin()
  ]
};
```

```
        <div
          class="fb-page"
          data-href="https://www.facebook.com/facebook"
          data-height="261px"
          data-width="358"
          data-hide-cover="false"
          data-show-facepile="false"
        ></div>
```

Checked every link,considering that problem belong in pagiation script loading

Comment: Looking at your webpack config, you're generating a `bundle.js` and not an `index.js`. Are you looking for `index.html` perhaps?

Comment: So basically I need to rename my bundle into index.js?

Comment: Did that nothing happened,like scripts are working(pagination,slider) but styles for pagination isn't,despite I haven't touched them for a while